# Is it possible to disable a device on plugging in another device in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, windows-10

I have suspected for a while now that the internal WiFi adapter of my laptop is shot (it stops working randomly until I manually disable and enable it), so I bought an external WiFi adapter (TP-Link Archer T4U) to fix this. However, when I don't have it plugged in, I would still like the internal adapter to switch on. So here is my question:

Is it possible to either use both adapters simultaneously (with the possibility to choose networks seperately on both cards), or to disable the internal adapter as soon as I plug the other in the USB port?

I have gotten the second solution to work under Debian using udev rules, but I can't seem to work it out under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, you'll need to create a couple of batch files that disable and enable your internal wifi adapter.  The Windows command that would do this is `devcon` and you will have to download it from Microsoft.  Based on a quick read of the [`devcon.exe`'s subcommands](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311272) you can disable and enable specific devices if you know their device names, which you can glean from `devmgmt.msc` or `devcon.exe` itself.

Then, wrap these batch files into a couple of Windows tasks from Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler.  Test them to make sure they work by running them manually first.

Then:

- Disconnect your external Wifi adapter.
- Open Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer.
- Open Windows Logs, then System on the left.
- Connect your external Wifi adapter.
- Refresh the log and look for events related to you plugging in the device (I've never done this, not sure what you will see or if you will see anything.)
- When you find the event, right click it select "Attach a task to this event..." and attach the task you defined earlier that will disablethe internal Wifi adapter.
- Disconnect your external Wifi adapter and then look for a disconnection event, and do the same thing.

Not 100% sure how well this would work, I've never tried it.